# Possible to use certain delimiters for macros with fancyvrb?

Tags: verbatim, catcodes, fancyvrb

In this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{AVerb}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\def\foo#1-#2;{}
\begin{document}
\begin{AVerb}
  \foo x-z;
\end{AVerb}
\end{document}
```

The use of `\foo` in `AVerb` produces an error:

```
! Argument of \foo has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.11   \foo x-z;
```

The catcode for `-` in the `AVerb` environment is 13 (active), but in normal text it is 12 (other).

I tried setting the catcode for `-` to 12 using `fancyvrb's` `codes` option but that didn't help. I believe this is because `-` can be a ligature and `fancyvrb` overrides my setting.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is exactly that: your delimiter has category code 12 and TeX can't find it in verbatim text where it's active exactly for the reason you're mentioning. The code

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`-
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def\foo #1~#2;}{}
```

will define `\foo` with the first argument delimited by an active `-`.

If you need `\foo` also in other places, then define it as you did and say also

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`-
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def\vfoo #1~#2;}{}
```

Then, with the help of the mighty `\usepackage{etoolbox}`, say

```
\preto{\AVerb}{\let\foo\vfoo}
```

(after having defined the `AVerb` environment).

How does the trick work? We set, in a group, the lowercase equivalent of `~` equal to `-`; the operation `\lowercase` acts only on characters (not on control sequences), *not* changing category codes. It does not expand or execute commands, but simply does the conversion and puts back the token list for examination by the input processor. Only after this conversion `\endgroup` is executed, so the equivalence is forgotten, but `~` has already been transformed into an active hyphen.

Comment: Defining `vfoo` works as advertised, though it took me awhile to figure out that the active status of ~ also played a role (in making - active). However, `\let\foo\vfoo` does not work -- I get the same error. But that's ok, I can use `\vfoo`.

Comment: @JustinBailey I've added a trick and also some comments.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the updated text. I haven't seen `etoolbox` before. Very nice!